# Using dplyr to group two variables and find the top three

Tags: r, dplyr

I thought I had this figured out, but I keep running in circles -- looking for some pointers. My understanding of `top_n` is it, essentially, combines `arrange` and `slice`, so if I'm looking for the top `n` items in a dataframe it will return those for me. But I'm not getting the result I expect.

The data I am working with is publication information -- the entire dataset is made up of rows for each author that correspond to a journal article title (`pubtitle`) and a journal (`journal_title`) and a publisher for that journal (`publisher`).

I made a subset of the entire dataframe that counts 1) the number of journal publishers (so, `publisher` is counted under `pub_publisher_count`), and 2) the number of articles that appear under a particular journal title (so, `pubtitle` is counted under `pub_title_count`). Here's a sampling of that new dataframe:

```
structure(list(publisher = c("Journal of Engineering Education", 
"Sage Publications, Inc.", "The Johns Hopkins University Press", 
"University of Ottawa", "American Society of Engineering Education", 
"Sage Publications, Inc.", "American Society of Engineering Education", 
"Sage Publications, Inc.", "Frontiers Research Foundation", "Public Library of Science", 
"Routledge", "American Society of Engineering Education", "American Society of Engineering Education", 
"Wiley-Blackwell Publishing, Inc.", "American Association for Agricultural Education", 
"American Psychological Association", "John Wiley & Sons Inc.", 
"Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers", "Springer New York LLC", 
"Sage Publications, Inc.", "Oxford University Press", "Sage Publications, Inc.", 
"American Society for Cell Biology", "Frontiers Research Foundation", 
"Routledge", "American Psychological Association", "Sage Publications, Inc.", 
"Routledge", "Elsevier Inc.", "Psychology Press"), pubtitle = c("Journal of Counseling and Development", 
"Psychology of Women Quarterly", "Journal of College Student Development", 
"University of Ottawa Journal of Medicine", "ASEE Annual Conference and Exposition, Conference Proceedings", 
"Personality and Social Psychology Bulletin", "ASEE Annual Conference and Exposition, Conference Proceedings", 
"Journal of Career Development", "Frontiers in Psychology", "PLoS ONE", 
"Journal of Educational Research", "ASEE Annual Conference and Exposition, Conference Proceedings", 
"ASEE Annual Conference and Exposition, Conference Proceedings", 
"Centaurus", "Journal of Agricultural Education", "Cultural diversity & ethnic minority psychology", 
"Science Education", "2007 37th Annual Frontiers In Education Conference - Global Engineering: Knowledge Without Borders, Opportunities Without Passports", 
"Research in Higher Education", "Personality and Social Psychology Bulletin", 
"Quarterly Journal of Economics", "Science Technology and Human Values", 
"Cell Biology Education", "Frontiers in Psychology", "International Journal of Science Education", 
"Journal of Applied Psychology", "Gender & Society", "NASPA Journal About Women in Higher Education", 
"Journal of vocational behavior", "Applied Developmental Science"
), pub_publisher_count = c(3L, 77L, 4L, 1L, 35L, 77L, 35L, 77L, 
20L, 13L, 51L, 35L, 35L, 27L, 4L, 25L, 15L, 12L, 76L, 77L, 13L, 
77L, 6L, 20L, 51L, 25L, 77L, 51L, 64L, 3L), pub_title_count = c(1L, 
13L, 2L, 1L, 32L, 5L, 32L, 4L, 14L, 10L, 1L, 32L, 32L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 7L, 2L, 13L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 1L
)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .Names = c("publisher", "pubtitle", "pub_publisher_count", 
"pub_title_count"))
```

I'm trying to find the top three titles for each journal publisher. So, for each publisher, they should be grouped together by name, and then within there the top three titles should also be grouped. In other words, I would see something like:

```
publisher        pubtitle
Sage             sage_title1
Sage             sage_title2
Sage             sage_title3
Springer         springer_title1
Springer         springer_title2
Springer         springer_title3
Publisher3       publisher3_title1
Publisher3       publisher3_title2
Publisher4       publisher4_title1
Publisher4       publisher4_title2
Publisher4       publisher4_title3
```

I thought I could get there with the below code, but I seem to be stuck:

```
pub_ownership %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    group_by(publisher) %>% 
    top_n(3, pub_title_count) %>% View()
```

I *seem* to be getting back a subset, but it's not correct in terms of prioritizing the journal title count (`pub_title_count`), nor does it group journal titles together (so, I'm getting a lot of repeated information).

Thanks for taking a look!

Edit: Here's another random sampling of data, with more repeat information that might be closer to how the actual dataset works.

```
structure(list(publisher = c("American Society of Engineering Education", 
"Elsevier Inc.", "Routledge", "Sage Publications, Inc.", "Elsevier Inc.", 
"Springer New York LLC", "Wiley-Blackwell Publishing, Inc.", 
"Sage Publications, Inc.", "American Society of Engineering Education", 
"M D P I AG", "American Psychological Association", "Journal of Engineering Education", 
"Elsevier Inc.", "Springer New York LLC", "Sage Publications, Inc.", 
"Sage Publications, Inc.", "Springer New York LLC", "Springer New York LLC", 
"Taylor & Francis Inc.", "American Psychological Association", 
"Public Library of Science", "John Wiley & Sons, Inc.", "Springer New York LLC", 
"Springer New York LLC", "Springer New York LLC", "Public Library of Science", 
"Elsevier Inc.", "Scientia Socialis", "Public Library of Science", 
"Addleton Academic Publishers", "American Psychological Association", 
"Elsevier Inc.", "American Society for Horticultural Science", 
"Routledge", "Springer New York LLC", "A I P Publishing LLC", 
"Elsevier Inc.", "Palgrave Macmillan Ltd.", "Institute for S T E M Education and Research", 
"Public Library of Science", "Routledge", "Routledge", "Learning Disabilities Worldwide", 
"EBSCO Publishing", "M D P I AG", "Sage Publications, Inc.", 
"Springer New York LLC", "Elsevier Inc.", "American Psychological Association", 
"Oxford University Press"), pubtitle = c("ASEE Annual Conference and Exposition, Conference Proceedings", 
"Research Policy", "Interdisciplinary Science Reviews", "Journal of Career Development", 
"Developmental Review", "Research in Higher Education", "Genome biology", 
"Review of Research in Education", "ASEE Annual Conference and Exposition, Conference Proceedings", 
"Social Sciences", "Journal of educational psychology", "Journal of Engineering Education", 
"Journal of vocational behavior", "Sex Roles", "Psychology of Women Quarterly", 
"Gifted Child Quarterly", "Social Psychology of Education", "Sex Roles", 
"Economic Geography", "Journal of Counseling Psychology", "Plos Biology", 
"Women in Higher Education", "Sex Roles", "Social Psychology of Education", 
"Research in Higher Education", "PLoS ONE", "Social Science Journal", 
"Journal of Baltic Science Education", "PLoS ONE", "Journal of Research in Gender Studies", 
"Journal of educational psychology", "Role of Gender in Educational Contexts and Outcomes", 
"Horttechnology", "International Journal of Science Education", 
"Research in Higher Education", "AIP Conference Proceedings", 
"Journal of vocational behavior", "Latino Studies", "Journal of STEM Education : Innovations and Research", 
"PLoS ONE", "Computer Science Education", "Chinese Sociological Review", 
"Insights on Learning Disabilities", "Teachers College Record", 
"Social Sciences", "Journal of Career Development", "Research in Higher Education", 
"Social science research", "Journal of Counseling Psychology", 
"Bioscience"), pub_publisher_count = c(35L, 64L, 51L, 77L, 64L, 
76L, 27L, 77L, 35L, 17L, 25L, 3L, 64L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 76L, 76L, 
4L, 25L, 13L, 7L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 13L, 64L, 1L, 13L, 2L, 25L, 
64L, 1L, 51L, 76L, 1L, 64L, 2L, 3L, 13L, 51L, 51L, 1L, 3L, 17L, 
77L, 76L, 64L, 25L, 13L), pub_title_count = c(32L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 32L, 16L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 21L, 13L, 1L, 5L, 21L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 21L, 5L, 13L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 13L, 1L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 16L, 4L, 13L, 
4L, 3L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .Names = c("publisher", "pubtitle", "pub_publisher_count", 
"pub_title_count"))
```

Comment: In your example, there are 30 rows and 18 publishers, so some will not have 3 rows of `pub_title_count`.

Comment: @akrun Running the code with the first example data, `z = group_by(DF, publisher) %>% top_n(3, pub_title_count) %>% arrange(publisher)` I can see the same publisher appearing on four rows, `n_distinct(z$publisher[3:6]) == 1L`. Seems like a bug or unclear documentation such that none of us know how to write the query correctly... Oh, I see, it's from ties.

Comment: I believe it does prioritize pub_title_count (but it's hard to see since it doesn't group or sort...), but if you can edit to show a counterexample, we could reopen.

Comment: @Frank yes, top_n shows a different behaviour with ties